# How do I get the bitrate for XHR uploads?

Tags: javascript, upload, xmlhttprequest, bitrate

How do I get the upload speed (bitrate) (i.e. kb/s, mb/s, etc) for uploads issued by an XHR request?

Comment: Use the XHR2 `onprogress` event to get the amount of data uploaded, and divide by the time taken.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I'm dividing the delta of the data loaded, by the delta of the amount of time elapsed, from the previous callback to the current callback.

time = formatFileSize ((evt.loaded - prev) / ((end - start) / 1000)) + '/s';